# UnboundLocalError when I try to open an invalid file name

Tags: python, file

I have written a program that takes a file name and returns numbers and it works as expected when the file name is inputted correctly but when I try to purposely write an incorrect file name, instead of giving me a "error: file not found" from the exception, it will say:

```
def getFile(fileName):
lines = []
try:
    infile = open(fileName, 'r')
    if infile != None:
        for line in infile:
         lines.append(line)

except IOError:
    print('Error: file not found.')

finally:
    infile.close()
return lines
```

Comment: Please add the error message and fix the indentation of the code.

Answer (score 1):

If an exception is raised by [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), the local variable `infile` is never declared let alone assigned, so the attempt to call `infile.close()` in the `finally` block will raise an `UnboundLocalError` as you see here. You can 'fix' this somewhat by declaring `infile` with some special uninitialized value (e.g. `None`) and checking explicitly like so:

```
def getFile(fileName):
    lines = []
    infile = None
    try:
        infile = open(fileName, 'r')
        for line in infile:
            lines.append(line)
    except IOError:
        print('Error: file not found.')
    finally:
        if infile is not None:
            infile.close()
    return lines
```

Alternatively, since file objects [are context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase), you can write something like:

```
def getFile(fileName):
    lines = []
    try:
        with open(fileName, 'r') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                lines.append(line)
    except IOError:
        print('Error: file not found.')
    return lines
```

... which will ensure `infile` is closed in a more syntactically concise & structured manner.

---

Note that on failure [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) raises an [`OSError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) (e.g. a [`FileNotFoundError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError)) rather than returning `None`, so your existing check is redundant.

Additionally, an `IOError` might be raised when iterating over the file rather than opening it initially, so the error message printed may be incorrect in those circumstances.

Lastly, since `infile` is an iterable, you can iteratively construct a list from it readily using the [constructor that accepts an iterable directly](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) like so:

```
return list(infile)
```